# Which pronoun is correct? "Xena named her/his sons Uther & Vlad"

Tags: pronouns

There is a lady Xena, and she has two boys. Let their names be Uther & Vlad.

1. *Xena named **her** sons Uther & Vlad.*
2. *Xena named **his** sons Uther & Vlad.*

Out of these 2 sentences which one is correct? And why? In some cases, while reading both look OK.

Comment: (2) definitely doesn't look OK to a native speaker, unless Xena  for some reason gave names to a man's sons by another woman.

Comment: Or just to her own sons by a specific man, implying that she might have had other sons by different men.

Comment: @KateBunting can we use just singular "son" there instead of plural "sons"?

Comment: @Man_From_India the count of children is 2, so it should be plural

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In English, the choice of pronoun depends on **the noun it replaces.**

If Xena is female, the pronoun must be *her.*

[Other languages may differ, having pronouns which are inflected according to the possession rather than the possessor: in French, both "his daughter" and "her daughter" would be "sa fille".]